# extact pattern with bash tool

Tags: extract

(a) 0.2.0-123-g9e17591

(b) 0.2.0-g9e17591

1. How to get 0.2.0-123 and 0.2.0 respectively ?
2. How to extract number 0 & 123 from "0.2.0-123-g9e17591" and
   2 & 0 from "0.2.0-g9e17591"

Comment: You can start with this `echo "0.2.0-123-g9e17591" | grep -Eo "(^[0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\-)([0-9]+)"` and this `echo "0.2.0-g9e17591" | grep -Eo "(^[0-9]+\.)([0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)"` and please make your question more clear.

Comment: Did you find anything posted useful? Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$ IFS='-' read -ra PARTS <<< 0.2.0-123-g9e17591
$ echo ${PARTS[*]}
```

to split the string into array `PARTS`, with `-` as a field separator, and then check the results.

Then you could proceed similarly with the first element of array `PARTS`

```
$ IFS='.' read -ra PARTS2 <<< ${PARTS[0]}
$ echo ${PARTS2[*]}
```

Repeat the operation as needed.

**Sources**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash
2. http://www.masteringunixshell.net/qa3/bash-how-to-echo-array.html
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685736/how-to-extract-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-bash

Comment: ...or process all in one go `IFS='.-'`

Comment: @bac0n - That is correct. The application depends on the expected structure of the inputs.